# Prevent new users from including links to explanatory images

Tags: feature-request, new-users, privileges, images, low-quality-posts

Stack Overflow is overflowed with questions from new users that ask "How can I do this?" with a link to some random image that "explain" it more clearly.

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655459/how-do-i-get-a-background-of-this-shape-in-html-css
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605270/one-portion-of-the-navbar-is-transparent-colorless-using-only-css
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656303/html-css-how-to-draw-a-rectangular-box-with-2-circles-in-it
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530380/how-to-get-data-and-refresh-it-in-keen-io-bootstrap-template
- And much more....

It's annoying, require more moderation and increases to amount of low-quality questions here.

I think that including a link to an image in a question should be a privilege earned after the user has asked some questions before and already had the chance to learn the rules on Stack Overflow, instead of encouraging those lazy sods to post low quality questions with no actual information and an image -  and to try and describe their actual problem WITH WORDS and CODE instead.

Comment: So... it seems like they already can't post images... because they're links instead of actual images... So you want to block them from including links entirely?

Comment: @Catija Just as SO doesn't allow to post snippets from jsfiddle without posting code in the question, I hope they can also identify that the link links to an image

Comment: I feel like you should just ask this on Meta SO and not here because there are some network sites that some good first questions do better with images in them.

Comment: Worth reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Thaks @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not talking about *uploading* images, but rather posting *links* to images, and there is a big difference, in my opinion.

New users with less than 10 reputation can't embed pictures in their posts, and greeted with this message when trying:

> [image]

So we're left with blocking a question if it contains a link to a picture.

Leaving aside the technical difficulty to detect such links (based on what? Look for any ".jpg", ".png", etc in the question? What if it's part of code), this is just not right. User has the right to say "This is what I want to have, visually" and as far as code is concerned, it's up to the user to add the code, and failing to do so will cause the question to be downvoted and closed.

Bottom line: I disagree with this feature request.

Comment: Is blocking embedding an image based on rep site-specific? Because 1-rep users do it on M&TV all the time.

Comment: I mean standart links in a question `(description)[link]` this is I guess how SO check for jsfiddle links and the absence of a supportive code snippet.

Comment: @Catija yes it's site specific and that's the reason it's not mentioned in the "Remove New User Restrictions" privilege in the Help Center. (because the text there can't be customized per site, as far as I know.)

Comment: Ah! That explains it. I was wondering why it wasn't included there on SO.

Comment: @Alon still, users will find ways to bypass it, plus my second argument which is not less important.

Comment: Well, I guess I have no other choice but accepting your answer. I don't agree with it, though I doubt SO will accept my idea based on the votes cast of my suggestion and your answer

Answer (score 3):

The problem with those questions is not that they include links to images, but rather what they don't include. Preventing links might cause one or two users to explain the whole thing in the question, but not the majority, who are relying on ESP anyway. And it would reduce the usefulness of some questions where the link (to the tutorial they are following, the book they are using, etc) is really helpful.

When I meet a question with a link to a useful image, I bring it inline to save others a click. (On some sites new users can't embed images, to prevent spam.) When I meet a question that is missing vital information, even it if has code, a link, to an image, or whatever, I do some or all of

- comment asking them to edit in the missing information
- vote to close if it can't be answered without the missing information
- downvote if I think that's appropriate

I suggest you develop similar habits.

Comment: Agreed, that's usually what i'm doing, depending on the quality of the question, but I do believe that recently there are more of a low quality posts then before  - And it's usually by users with 1 rep. (Just making sure that you understand that I suggested preventing only links **to images**, not to ban all types of links from new users)